# Fstab - Parse error at line

Tags: fstab

I'm giving up. I tried many changes, but can't find what is wrong.
In fstab file I have this line:

```
https://webdav.pcloud.com /home/pi/pCloud davfs auto,_netdev,rw,user 0 0
```

If I try to "sudo mount -a", I'm getting an error:

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 9 -- ignored
```

What is wrong? I tried with changing all parameters (step by step), but nothing helps. Folder is available, web address is available, options are correct, EOF is there ...

Any idea?

Comment: If I copy and paste this line into my fstab and mount, it works. You sure this is the line it is complaing about? Try copy and pasting yourself, maybe you have weird characters somewhere in the file.

Comment: Unbelievable. It works! So there must be something strange in one of the characters (space?). After copy from Windows (this forum) to Linux (fstab) the same line, it works. :-) Thank you.